Convert SQL Server varchar column to date based on a format
I need to convert a varchar column representing dates based on format to date in SQL Server. I have tried below but it gives me an error. The format of varchar date column is as below
YYYY-mm-dd
Select CONVERT(date, '1403-02-17', 103)


Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 171
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.


Have you looked at the official documentation? All the formats including the one you are using are listed.

If we look at the documentation @DaleK references, we can see that style 103 is dd/mm/yyyy; your date does not look like that.

The style number 103 is for the format dd/mm/yyyy. However, your date format is YYYY-mm-dd. Try one of these syntaxes without specifying any number style. It will convert the string into a date object on the fly:
SELECT CONVERT(date, '1403-02-17');

or
SELECT CAST('1403-02-17' AS date);

If you want to have the output in dd/mm/yyyy format you may also use formatting after converting it into a date object:
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('1403-02-17' AS date), 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS FormattedDate;

Foot note for Hijri Dates:
Be careful if you are using datediff or other date functions on Hijri dates because SQL Server will interpret the string as a Gregorian date by default. To correctly handle Hijri dates, you should use the Hijri calendar explicitly. For Shamsi you may need extra functions rather than built in functions.

@Mah_Bar any reason not to accept this answer?
